# fatal error: QCAR/QCAR.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android-ndk, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to run a Vuforia sample project, in android studio.
Android NDK is ready to use and i can build NDK samples.
Vuforia Image Target sample app is imported and Vuforia.Jar library added as dependency.
But when i build the project, i see this:
`fatal error: QCAR/QCAR.h: No such file or directory`
Can anyone help me? Why this error appears?

Comment: How did you get it fixed for Android Studio. I am having same error

Comment: Solution is as below, just follow vuforia tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the installation location of Vuforia SDK is correct.

From the official website of Vuforia:
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Vuforia-Android-SDK

> The Vuforia SDK is distributed as a ZIP package for the following
>   platforms: Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.
>
> To start developing with the Vuforia  SDK:
>
> - Download the Vuforia SDK (you need to accept the license agreement before the download can start)
> - Extract the contents of the ZIP package and put it into
> - Adjust the Vuforia Environment settings in Eclipse
>
> Once extracted, the SDK package reveals a directory structure in your
>   Android development environment. This structure ensures that sample
>   apps can be easily built and deployed using the Android NDK and the
>   Eclipse Java developer environment.